# using Auth::id() Eloquent only when creating and updating

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i need help in using Auth::id() Eloquent only when creating and updating.
what i am trying to achieve is, when i use Eloquent model save or update, the current logged in user id to be added to touched_by field.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Account extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes;
  public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
  {
      $this->setRawAttributes(array_merge($this->attributes, array(
        'touched_by' => Auth::id()
      )), true);
      parent::__construct($attributes);
  }

  /**
   * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

But this will give me the current loggedin user when i do Model::all() ?

Comment: maybe something like this $user = Auth::user(); 

'touched_by' => $user->id

Comment: Auth::id() works, but the problem is i want the eloquent to insert current user automatically,

Comment: `class Users extends Eloquent  {

...

public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

// create a event to happen on updating
        static::updating(function($table)  {
            $table->updated_by = Auth::user()->username;
        });

// create a event to happen on deleting
        static::deleting(function($table)  {
            $table->deleted_by = Auth::user()->username;
        });

// create a event to happen on saving
        static::saving(function($table)  {
            $table->created_by = Auth::user()->username;
        });
}

...

}`

Comment: paste here please https://paste.laravel.io/

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/z3xZ6